# What's the difference between "temporary" and "session" when allowing cookies with the CookieSafe addon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, cookies

Session is "until the browser is closed", right? But what does it mean then to allow cookies "temporarily"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Allow example.com for session" allows the site to set cookies for the *current and all future sessions*.  Every time you open Firefox, the site will be allowed to set cookies.
- "Temporarily allow example.com" allows the site to set cookies *for the current session only*.  The next time you open Firefox, that site will not be allowed to set cookies.

In both cases, the cookies are deleted each time Firefox is closed.

Comment: So, when I "allow example.com for session", what am I disallowing? To set a cookie expiry that extends beyond the session?

Comment: @Hanno: When you use "Allow example.com for session", you're not allowing the cookies to persist across browser sessions. They get deleted every time you close Firefox. This prevents the site from "remembering" you and potentially gathering information about your browsing habits that you may not want them to have.  It's also a security measure as information such as cached log-in credentials will be deleted.

Comment: @raven: according to my experience, and as I said in my answer, the permission is temporary, not the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Not much information out there in the interweb about CookieSafe, but I would guess that temporarily means that you can accept cookies for only that time that you are on the site that is trying to add a cookie. If you leave the site and come back, the cookies will be blocked and you will have to allow it again.

Answer (score -1):

These are permissions for a site to store cookies for this site in Firefox.

"Allow for session" means that the said site is allowed to store cookies for this invocation of firefox. Cookies are still kept after Firefox is closed, and are used if you launch Firefox again (however the site won't be able to store new ones).

"Allow" means that the said site will always be able to store any cookies it likes.